# Why do server mainboards use different capacitors for their VRMs?

Tags: voltage-regulator, cpu, computers

Recently I noticed that server mainboards use a different type of capacitor as part of their VRMs (after the inductor). I believe they are ceramic capacitors, whereas consumer boards usually use electrolytic capacitors. What is the reason for this? What advantages do each have in the context of Mainboards? As an example, I have included images two Asus mainboards, one being the server part (Z10PA-D8), the other the workstation/consumer counterpart (Z10PE-D8). If you look at the area next to the socket, you can see the different capacitor types being used.

[image: VRM comparison]

Comment: Did you "notice" this in just these two boards? Or others? Because it takes many, many, ceramic capacitors to replace a single electrolytic (otherwise we would just use ceramics everywhere due to superior frequency response). Are you sure the electrolytics just aren't elsewhere?

Comment: This is my thought exactly! But then the question would be, where are they? Both mainboards support the same CPUs, both going up to 160W TDP. I would expect there to be at least on electrolytic capacitor for each inductor... But if you look at the image on the the Website of Asus (https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/Z10PAD8/gallery/), you cannot fine them.

Comment: Are there tantalums on the server board? Maybe the server board uses A much much higher frequency SMPS? Or coupled inductors? Or more phases? (mobos already use a ton of phases though).

Comment: It should be noted that many electrolytic capacitors dry out over time and therefore have a definite lifespan after which they don't work very well.  Whereas ceramic capacitors don't have that limitation.  If one was designing a product that was meant to last a long time they might choose ceramic for that reason.  Weather that's the case for these server boards, I can't say.

Comment: @user4574 There are solid electrolytics now that do not dry out, as well as hybrids which are a mix of solid and liquid kind do(?)

Comment: high performance ceramic caps are more expensive for low ESR at SRF

Comment: @DKNguyen I cannot see any, but perhaps they are integrated or on the backside? That would explain why I rarely see them on images. Say they were using tantalums, why would they not use them also on the workstation board (which is also very expensive and requires high reliability)?

Comment: Tants cost more than electros and can explode of improperly designed for. They are being phased out. Unlikely to be integrated.

Comment: servers usually have higher quality PSUs than consumer gear, and they (usually) don't have a GPU unexpectedly sucking up all the watts.

Answer (score 0):

Except from the advantages/disadvantages of each capacitor type (you can find these online), there might be others, realted to manufacturing or project limitations like:

Manufacturing cost, space available, availability of capacitor types, weight etc.

For example in a factory location where they design high quality boards, Electrolytic capacitors might be more expensive than Ceramic (due to the location or shipping difficulties), so they will choose to use Ceramic ones to reduce the cost a little bit.

I dont have any specific idea why they would use each type of capacitor on each situation.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that it's almost universally true that BOTH ceramic and electrolytic (and often other types as well) are used in both consumer and server board products.

The reason is that different capacitors have different characteristics and the designer of the board knows that using one type alone will not suffice.

For example, ceramic caps are good for high-frequency and transient response and are often used to decouple near power inputs to ICs.

Electrolytic caps have higher capacitance for the same volume and are usually used as filter capacitors on power planes.

Different capacitors are used for different reasons and in this case one size or type does not fit all.